# C# save image to memory stream

Tags: c#

I just want to save an image bmp for my screen to a memory stream gut I get:

> value cannot be null. parameter name encoder

I use this code

```
pmb = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
gc = Graphics.FromImage(pmb);
gc.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(pmb.Width, pmb.Height));
pb.Image = pmb;
pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

try
{
    client = new TcpClient(mm.Text, 1430);
    ms = new MemoryStream();
    pb.Image.Save(ms, pb.Image.RawFormat);
    ms.Close();
    byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
    ns = client.GetStream();
    br = new BinaryWriter(ns);
    br.Write(buffer);
    br.Close();
    ns.Close();
    client.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Please debug your code and specify line where it throws (I'd be surprised if it is anywhere from this code).

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing your MemoryStream after you close it

```
ms.Close();
byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
```

Also, if an Exception is ever thrown, you will not clean up resources.  Make use of the `using` keyword for everything that implements IDisposable.

You need to rewind the memory stream after writing to it and before saving it out

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: same i change the code
ms.Close();
byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();

Comment: @alexmike Changed it to what?

Comment: i searched  in google maybe the problem of image format

Comment: i chnage it to 

 ms = new MemoryStream();

                pb.Image.Save(ms, pb.Image.RawFormat);

                byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
                ms.Close();

Comment: @alexmike why are you using `GetBuffer`? `ToArray` is probably more suitable if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Eric J, I don't believe that particular problem is due to using steam after closing - `GetBuffer`/`ToArray` explicitly allowed to be used after `Close`/`Dispose` on `MemoryStream`....

Comment: @Alexei: Interesting.  Do you have a reference for that?  Just looked at GetBuffer in MSDN and don't see mention of that one way or the other.  The issue could well still be from the MemoryStream not being rewound (or at least, that could be a further issue... unclear where exactly the error is happening).

Comment: Iam new in c# and i think i do it like this but same problem 

client = new TcpClient(mm.Text, 1430);
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                pb.Image.Save(ms, pb.Image.RawFormat);
                //byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();

                byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
                ms.Close();
                ns = client.GetStream();
                br = new BinaryWriter(ns);





                br.Write(data);

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i change it 
i get buffer before close

Comment: @EricJ. the error on 

pb.Image.Save(ms, pb.Image.RawFormat);

Comment: Rewind the memory stream as suggested `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` I think your call to Save is not seeing all of the data because the stream is already at the end.

Comment: @EricJ. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx: "This method works when the memory stream is closed." (same for `ToArray`).

Comment: LOL i slove it 

i just change

pb.Image.Save(ms, pb.Image.RawFormat);

to

 pb.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);

with library
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Answer (score -1):

It is save memory

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox_ad_cam_in.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
kanvert = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
```